# How can I merge two rows together and sum them?

Tags: r

I've looked through the other problems that have been solved on here, and I can't find anything that quite fits my data and the solution I am looking for yet.

After cleaning my data, I get an output that looks something like this (slimmed down for ease):

| Gender | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Agender | 9 |
| Female | 15 |
| Genderfluid | 10 |
| Non Binary | 2 |
| Male | 14 |

For a summary, I would like the output to look like below, combining the other gender identity categories (not male or female) into one Other gender identity category, however I am uncertain how to combine the rows and sum them. Is there something I could do to combine the gender identity values to create this output below?

| Gender | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Female | 15 |
| Male | 14 |
| Other Gender Identity | 21 |

I have tried the following

```
df <- aggregate(df, list(Group=replace(rownames(df$gender),rownames(df$gender) %in% c("Agender","Genderfluid","Non-binary"), "Transgender")), sum)
```

which I found in another output, but this isn't working for me, it is just coming up with an error!

Comment: So you want to go to just three categories? Could you share your data as a `dput`?

Comment: It is probably easiest to compute the total of 9, 10 and 2 in your head and just write the result down. You might want to do this in code under certain circumstances but you have not given a wirkable example in R Code so we do not know the structure of your data in R, so writing code is unneccessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(gender = ifelse(!gender %in% c("Male", "Female"), "Other", gender)) %>% 
   group_by(gender) %>% 
   summarise(Total = sum(total))

    # A tibble: 3 × 2
      gender Total
      <chr>  <dbl>
    1 Female    15
    2 Male      14
    3 Other     21
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an aggregation group and aggregate (data.table solution below). In the code below it is good to check if you don't have cell values in the gender column which are uncapitalized (e.g. "male" instead of "Male") or something like that. This would lead them to be added to the "Other Gender Identity" group.

```
#load library
library(data.table)

#example data
dt <- data.table(gender = c("Agender", "Female", "Genderfluid", "Non Binary", "Male"),
                 Total = c(9,15,10,2,14))

#create group for aggregation
dt[!gender %in% c("Female", "Male"), group := "Other Gender Identity"]
dt[gender %in% c("Female", "Male"), group := gender]

#aggregate
dt[, sum(Total), by = group]
dt

                   group V1
1: Other Gender Identity 21
2:                Female 15
3:                  Male 14
```

Comment: Or create group on the fly: `dt[, sum(Total), by = .(group = fifelse(gender %in% c("Female", "Male"), gender, "Other"))]`

Answer (score 1):

Using *replace* and *aggregate*:

```
with(df,
     aggregate(x = Total, 
               by = list(Group = replace(Gender, !Gender %in% c("Male", "Female"), "Other")), 
               FUN = "sum"))
#     Group  x
# 1  Female 15
# 2    Male 14
# 3   Other 21
```